# Laravel - Auth, route is not logged

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I've a problem when route call a method of Controller after login successfull.
In the new method user seems to be not logged. 
I can't understand why.

Steps are: Log-in with

```
Route::post('login', 'UserController@login')->name('login');
```

and than check if user is logged with:

```
Route::get('check-login', 'UserController@checklogged');
```

Controller is this one:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

class UserController extends Controller
{
  // regole per FormValidator
  protected $rulesLogin = [
    'email' => 'bail|required|email',
    'password' => 'required',
  ];



  // Effettuo il login
  /**
   *  Method: POST
   * @Parameters: email, password
   * return: Authenticated User.
   */
  public function login(Request $request)
  {
    //dd($request->all());

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),$this->rulesLogin);

    // login fallito
    if ($validator->failed()) {
      return response([
        'status' => 'ko',
        'message' => $validator->errors()->first(),
      ], 422);
    }

    // login errato
    if (!Auth::attempt([
      'email' => $request->email,
      'password' => $request->password,
      'status' => ['active'],
    ])) {
      return response(
        [
          'status' => 'ko',
          'message' => 'Invalid email or password',
        ], 422);
    }

    return (Auth::user());
  }

  public function checklogged()
  {
    return dd(Auth::id());
  }
```

checklogged() return always false. I expect it return a user logged Id

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is u havent used web midlleware in route.If you are following HMVC pattern make sure to use web middleware like this.

```
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => ['web'],

    ], function () {

    });
```

or please check your RouteServiceProvider.php  file weather it has web middleware in mapWebRoutes() function

```
   protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware('web')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

problem was middleware as guest.

```
Route::post('login', 'UserController@login')->name('login')->middleware('guest');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this sintaxe:

```
public function checklogged()
  {
    return dd(Auth::user()->id);
  }
```